# Xcode/Cocoapods why can't I implement a Swift protocol from a Pod?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm having an odd problem with a project not being able to implement a swift protocol in a relatively large mixed ObjC/Swift project.

Our work project is about the app 50K lines of code, and about 20 Cocoapods.  The project is originally an ObjC project, but now it's about 60% Swift3 and 40% ObjC.

I'm working on Xcode 8.3.3, but also see the problem in XCode 9-GM

The cocoapods are a mix of Swift and ObjC.  This all works fine, so normally calling swift from ObjC or ObjC from Swift works fine.

However, this may be the first time I'm trying to implement an Swift Protocol (that's marked with the `@objc` flag) in a UIViewController.

I recently added the cocoapod `CountryPickerSwift` (https://cocoapods.org/pods/CountryPickerSwift).  In one of my ViewControllers, added an extension to implement the protocol from CountryPicker: `CountryPickerDelegate`:

```
import CountryPicker

class PhoneCountryCodePickerViewController: UIViewController {

    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.countryPicker.countryPickerDelegate = self
    }

    // ...

}

extension PhoneCountryCodePickerViewController: CountryPickerDelegate {
    func countryPhoneCodePicker(_ picker: CountryPicker, didSelectCountryWithName name: String, countryCode: String, phoneCode: String, flag: UIImage) {
        NSLog ("country: \(name), countryCode: \(countryCode), phoneCode: \(phoneCode)")
    }
}
```

Inside the `CountryPicker` codebase, the `CountryPickerDelegate` is defined as:

```
@objc public protocol CountryPickerDelegate {
   func countryPhoneCodePicker(_ picker: CountryPicker, didSelectCountryWithName name: String, countryCode: String, phoneCode: String, flag: UIImage)
}
```

This is super simple and should work fine.

However, when I try to run, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CountryPickerDelegate'
MyWorkProject-Swift.h
```

(obviously my work project isn't called MyWorkProject, but whatever).

In the `MyWorkProject-Swift.h` file I see:

```
@import CountryPicker;

// ...

@class CountryPicker;

// ...

@interface PhoneCountryCodePickerViewController (SWIFT_EXTENSION(Playlist)) <CountryPickerDelegate>
- (void)countryPhoneCodePicker:(CountryPicker * _Nonnull)picker didSelectCountry:(Country * _Nonnull)country;
@end
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.  I've tried renaming the Delegate protocol in case there was some odd collision, but that doesn't help.

Again, all other ObjC <-> Swift interoperability works fine.  It's just this one.

I know this should work though.

I created a new project as an example to prove (to myself) that it should indeed work fine. Here are the steps I used:

- created a project that was started as an ObjC project
- added a swift file to setup the Bridging Header
- added the `CountryPickerSwift` cocoapod.
- Added the `PhoneCountryCodePickerViewController` (that implements the offending `CountryPickerDelegate`)from the work project wholesale.

The sample project is here: https://github.com/SuperTango/CountryPickerExample and works fine.  I've inspected the CountryPickerExample-Swift.h file and as far as the CountryPicker code goes, it's exactly the same as the Work Project "-Swift.h" file.

I can't figure out why the work project fails but the example project succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using my library.
Fixed in pod version 1.4.5. Use latest version

Comment: Great.  What was the problem?